# Expected an indented block in python

Tags: python

Hey guys I've been trying to run this code, but I keep getting this error saying "Expected an indented block"
I'm new to python and I don't understand what the problem is. I have indented the code properly according to my knowledge.

```
import sys, string
wordsize = 24 # everything is a word
numregbits = 3 # actually +1, msb is indirect bit
opcodesize = 5
memloadsize = 1024 # change this for larger programs
numregs = 2**numregbits
opcposition = wordsize - (opcodesize + 1) # shift value to position opcode
reg1position = opcposition - (numregbits + 1) # first register position
reg2position = reg1position - (numregbits + 1)
memaddrimmedposition = reg2position # mem address or immediate same place as reg2
startexecptr ==0
def regval ( rstr ): # help with reg or indirect addressing
    if rstr.isdigit():
        return ( int( rstr ) )
    elif rstr[0] == '*':
        return int ( rstr[1:]  + (1<<numregbits)) 
    else:
        return 0 # should not happen
        mem = [0] * memloadsize # this is the memory load executable
# instruction mnemonic, type: (1 reg, 2 reg, reg+addr, immed, pseudoop), opcode
        opcodes = {'add': (2, 1),'sub': (2, 2),
           'dec': ( 1, 3), 'inc': ( 1, 4 ),
           'ld': (3, 7), 'st': (3, 8), 'ldi': (3, 9),
           'bnz': (3, 12), 'brl': (3, 13),
           'ret': ( 1, 14 ),
           'int': (3, 16), 'sys': (3, 16),
           'dw': (4, 0), 'go':(3, 0), 'end': (0, 0) }       
        curaddr = 0 # start assembling to location 0
#for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r').readlines(): # command line
        infile = open("in.asm", 'r')
# Build Symbol Table
        symboltable = {}
        for line in infile.readlines(): # read our asm code
                tokens = string.split( string.lower( line )) # tokens on each line
                firsttoken = tokens[0]
    if firsttoken.isdigit(): # if line starts with an address
        curaddr = int( tokens[0] ) # assemble to here
        tokens = tokens[1:]
    if firsttoken == ';': # skip comments
    if firsttoken == 'go': # start execution here
        startexecptr = ( int( tokens[ 1 ] ) & ((2**wordsize)-1)) # data
    if firsttoken[0] == '.':
        symboltable[firsttoken] = curaddr
        curaddr = curaddr + 1
        print symboltable
        infile.close()
infile = open("in.asm", 'r')
    for line in infile.readlines():
        tokens = string.split( string.lower( line )) # tokens on each line
        firsttoken = tokens[0]
    if firsttoken.isdigit(): # if line starts with an address
        curaddr = int( tokens[0] ) # assemble to here
        tokens = tokens[1:]
    if firsttoken == 'go': # start execution here
        startexecptr = ( int( tokens[ 1 ] ) & ((2**wordsize)-1))
    if firsttoken[0] == '.':
        symaddr = symboltable[firsttoken]
        tokens = tokens[1:]
        memdata = 0
        instype = opcodes[ tokens[0] ] [0]
        memdata = ( opcodes[ tokens[0] ] [1] ) << opcposition
    if instype == 4: # dw type
        memdata = ( int( tokens[ 1 ] ) & ((2**wordsize)-1))
    elif instype == 0: # end type
        memdata = memdata
    elif instype == 1: # dec,inc type, one reg
        memdata = memdata + (regval( tokens[1] ) << reg1position)
    elif instype == 2: # add, sub type, two regs
        memdata = memdata + ( regval( tokens[1] ) << reg1position ) + ( regval( tokens[2] ) << reg2position)
    elif instype == 3: # ld,st type
        token2 = tokens[2]
    if token2.isdigit():
        memaddr = int( tokens[2] )
    else:
        memaddr = symboltable[ token2 ]
        memdata = memdata + ( regval( tokens[1] ) << reg1position ) + memaddr
        mem[ curaddr ] = memdata # memory image at the current location
        curaddr = curaddr + 1
        outfile = open("a.out", 'w') # done, write it out
        outfile.write( 'go ' + '%d' % startexecptr ) # start execution here
        outfile.write( "\n" )
    for i in range(memloadsize): # write memory image
        outfile.write( hex( mem[ i ] ) + " " + '%d'%i)
        outfile.write( "\n" )
        outfile.close()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. We can't see yours magically

Comment: You mean I should post the other codes related to this too ?

Comment: Haidro means the *full* error message, which would likely indicate the line number where things started going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `if` lines indented to the same level:

```
if firsttoken == ';': # skip comments
if firsttoken == 'go': # start execution here
```

Did you mean to indent everything after the first?

If your own editor is showing the two lines as being on different indentation levels, you need to stop mixing tabs and spaces; Python is interpreting tabs differently from your editor.

Run your script with `python -tt <scriptname>` to have Python tell you where you are misusing tabs.

Comment: i think he wants `if firsttoken == ';':` `pass`

Comment: I'd say `continue` instead of `pass` in that case.

Comment: But frankly, indentation in the question here is an absolute mess; the program flow makes little sense as posted.

Comment: Yeah as I'm new to this language I am not clear about the indentation.
Also, I read somewhere that the 'continue' cannot be used with 'if', hence I dint use continue